# Pass child component value back to parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a `sidebar` the toggles on and off. Currently, when I use the following code, the side bar opens as expected:

```
<Sidebar show={status} />

  <button onClick={() => setStatus((status) => !status)}>
      <SettingsIcon/>
  </button>
```

I use both true and false values for `status` to toggle the sidebar on and off.

Now, in my sidebar component, I need to pass a `false` value to `show` so that is closes when my `Back` button is clicked.

```
const Sidebar = ({ show }) => {
  const { left } = useSpring({
    from: { left: "-100%" },
    left: show ? "0" : "-100%",
  });

  return (
    <animated.div
      style={{
        left: left,
        position: "absolute",
        height: "100%",
        width: "55%",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        zIndex: 1,
      }}
      className="Sidebar"
    >
      <button onClick={() => !show}>Back</button>
      <p>hello</p>
    </animated.div>
  );
};
```

I can't seem to get it working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `onClick` callback from parent to child and keep the `show` variable in the parent component.

Parent:

```js
<Sidebar show={status} onClose={() => setShow(!show)} />
    <button onClick={() => setStatus((status) => !status)}>
        <SettingsIcon/>
    </button>
</Sidebar>
```

Child:

```js
const Sidebar = ({ show, onClose }) => {
  const { left } = useSpring({
    from: { left: "-100%" },
    left: show ? "0" : "-100%",
  });

  return (
    <animated.div
      style={{
        left: left,
        position: "absolute",
        height: "100%",
        width: "55%",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        zIndex: 1,
      }}
      className="Sidebar"
    >
      <button onClick={onClose}>Back</button>
      <p>hello</p>
    </animated.div>
  );
};
```

Comment: So what should I write in my child component?